# Find all $(a, b, c) \in \mathbb R^3$ satisfying the following system of equations:

Tags: systems-of-equations, real-numbers

Find all $(a, b, c) \in \mathbb R^3$ satisfying the following system of equations:
$$ \begin{cases} a^{2} = \dfrac{ {b}^3 + 9 \sqrt{3} }{3b} = \dfrac{ {c}^3 + 16 }{3c} \\ \\ b^{2} = \dfrac{ {a}^3 - 10 }{3a} = \dfrac{ {c}^{3} + 28 }{3c} \\ \\ c^{2} = \dfrac{ {b}^{3} + 45 \sqrt{3} }{3b} = \dfrac{ {a}^3 - 88 }{3a} \end{cases}$$

One possible way to solve this system of equations is as follows:

From the first equation, we can write:
\begin{align}
a^2 &= \dfrac{b^3 + 9\sqrt{3}}{3b} \\
3a^2 b &= b^3 + 9\sqrt{3} \end{align}

Simplifying and rearranging, we get:
$$b^3 - 3a^2 b + 9\sqrt{3} = 0$$

This is a cubic equation in $b$. We can solve it using any method for solving cubic equations, such as Cardano's formula or numerical methods.
By solving this I get
​
\begin{align}
a & \approx 1 \\
b & \approx \sqrt[3]{-6\sqrt{3} - 3} + \sqrt[3]{-6\sqrt{3} + 7} \\
c & \approx -0.147.\end{align}

But the answer of this question is
$a=-2 , b=\sqrt 3, c=-4$.
What are the other possible ways to solve this question?

Comment: From the step "This is a cubic equation in $b$" on it's not clear what you did. How did you arrive to those numbers? The solution is indeed $a=-2, b=\sqrt{3}, c=-4$. Also, how did you write your question? You have a very odd mixture of MathJax and other math notation.

Comment: That's an an overdetermined system with $6$ equations and $3$ unknowns. Is that the original problem, or something you derived while solving another problem? Anyway, you can't solve one cubic for two unknowns. Instead, you could start with the two "nicer" equations involving $a,c$ which are $3 a^2 c = c^3 + 16$, $3 a c^2 = a^3 - 88$. Eliminating $c$ between them [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28-3+a%5E2+c+%2B+c%5E3+%2B+16%2C+-3+a+c%5E2+%2B+a%5E3+-+88%2C+c%29+%3D+0) a cubic in $a^3$ with real roots $a=-2, 1 \pm 2 \sqrt{3}$, then you would have to check each one in turn.

Comment: Alt. hint: $\;$ the $6$ equations are equivalent to:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
(a - ib)^3 &= 10 - 9\sqrt{3} \,i
\\ (b - ic)^3 &= - 45 \sqrt{3} - 28\,i
\\ (c - ia)^3 &= -16 + 88\,i
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$